# can we trade off electric power for time?

Tags: voltage, power, current, energy, discharge

The voltage and current are exchangable for a constant power. **Can we increase the power of the source by decreasing the time of the supply ?**

From this equation

> Power = Energy / Time

The total energy of the source is constant, so by reducing the time of the supply we can increase the power. If the source is a battery then by making the battery discharge faster we can increase the power output. **But, how to do it?**

And also for, what **if the source was a constant power supply ?**

Comment: There is no one universal way of using a constant amount of energy with a variable time quota. What do you want to do?

Comment: a Method (simply a device or circuit) to increase the power by making the battery discharge faster (like a voltage booster for voltage)

Comment: What is it that you want to power?

Comment: I am currently making a piezo-elctric power generator (for simple applications) but it produces low power, so, that i want to make a circuit that converts lower power to higher power.

Comment: Then the simple answer to this question is No, you cannot. The only way of doing so would be if you use the generator to charge a battery or similar energy storage. Then you can leverage the increased use of time in order to generate more energy. Once the battery is charged, it can be discharged fast -> More power for a limited time.

Comment: Thanks man for your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Can we increase the power of the source by decreasing the time of the
> supply ?*

Unfortunately, the power of a source is just that but...

> *can we trade off electric power for time?*

**Absolutely we can.**

If the source has a limited energy then, we can choose to use that energy (within reason) how we like. It's average power that you cannot do much about.

For instance, if you have a 1 watt supply source, you can accumulate the energy from that source (1 joule per second) into a capacitor (for instance) and deliver a peak of 1 kW every second but, only for a duration of 1 millisecond.

I've designed a circuit that charges a capacitor from a 500 watts supply and delivers peaks of several megawatts into a load (that I'm unfortunately prevented from talking about). It doesn't deliver the several megawatts for very long and, there is a several tens of second re-charge time but, in effect, I'm trading time for peak power.

> *But, how to do it?*

Energy storage into big capacitors and rapid discharge into a powerful load. You need to do this efficiently of course and switching regulators are the turn-to solution.

Comment: How do you use it for to produce continious power output ?

Comment: You can't. You can't expect the long-term output power from a circuit to be greater than the long-term input power. That's against the laws of physics. Energy out cannot be greater than energy in over a long period (simple words).

Comment: so we need to charge and discharge the capacitor continiously, right. I am currently making a piezo-elctric power generator but it produces lower power. That's why i am asking. Thank you for your answer

Comment: You can take more power from a battery by connecting a load that takes more current.

Comment: what if the load has constant resistance (I mentioned briefly about this in the comment of @Sandro's answer)

Comment: @Logesh-0304 sorry but this is going around in circles. Load power taken from a battery is \$V^2/R\$ where R is the load resistance and V is the battery voltage. You do the math. So either lower the load resistance or use a voltage converter to increase the voltage.

Comment: Can we use this method to discharge a battery to charge another battery faster (faster discharging and faster charging)

Comment: @Logesh-0304 this is a question and answer site and not a forum or talking shop. I have answered the question you raised at the top of this page. Comments are for requesting clarification of the details in my answer. Moderators may close this conversation down as inappropriate. This isn't like other sites; it's more focussed. You ask a question and you get an answer. If that creates a whole new train of thought then ask a brand-new question. That's what this site is about.

Answer (score 0):

Most power supplies can be approximated as an ideal voltage generator (U0) in series with an internal resistor r.

Let's consider a resistive load R.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZocTC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The current will be I=U0/(r+R)
So the "usefull" power you get in your resistor is P=R*I² = U0²*R/(R+r)²
Which is maximum for R=r

So the maximum (continuous) power you can theoretically get out of your power supply is P=U0²/(4*r).
Note that many power supplies have a quite low internal resistance r, so you might destroy them if trying to pull that much current out of them.

There, you get already a first trick to get "more" instant power out of a power supply (for exemple a lithium battery) : many supplies suport far more instant power than continuous power, so as long as you are switching fst enough, you can use a smaller load resistor R without getting out of specs.

The next step, is to use a big capacitor (with high current ratings and low internal resistance (ESR)) and put it in parralel with your power supply :
That way, for short bursts, you will mainly pull current from the capacitor, which has (often) far lower internal resistance and bigger current rating. The average power however is not increased (you need to recharge the capacitor in between).

If you get a fixed load you want to supply a lot of power to, then you can no longuer just decrease the resistance of your load to harvest all the power you can. Instead, you will have to increase the voltage : you connect a boost converter on your power supply to increase the power as high as you want ; then you add a big capacitor in parallel to the output of the converter to get instant current capabilities as big as you want : that way, you load gets high voltage with as much current as it pulls at that voltage (nb : don't forget, it's just bursts, the capacitors need to be recharged in between)

So to sumerize :

- there is no way to get more than P=U0²/(4*r) average power out of a power supply (hoften less, because it doesn't support such a high power)
- you can get instant power as high as you want by converting to high voltage and ading capacitors to provide the required instant current capabilities. However, this works only for short bursts, because it doesn't increases the average power (ie the higher the instant power, the smaller the proportion of time you can use it)

Comment: But, by making the battery discharge faster, we can produce higher power without using capacitors to charge and discharge. How do you make the battery discharge faster to produce higher power

Comment: To discharge the battery "faster", you have to reduce the resistance of your load. The fastest you can discharge it is by shorting it (0 ohm resistance between + and -). Of course, many batteries would be distroyed if you short them (at least if you do it for too long or repeateadly). Some might even ignite or explode if you short them.

So if you want to empty the battery as fast as possible, use a load with a resistor as small as possible (to get maximal current) while remaining within th current limits of your battery

Comment: However, if you put a very small load, the POWER received by the load will decrease (because power = voltage * current, and voltage decreeses when current increases due to the internal resistance of your battery. So if you want to get maximum power, your load resistor must be equal to the internal resistor (in that case the power for your load is maximal (but you waist the same amount in the internal resistance)). If the battery don't support that high current, then take a load resistance as small as possible while remaining with current inside the limits of the battery

Comment: If i connect the battery to a electrical device (that has a constant resistance) then how i decrease the resistance of the device. I know if we connect a resistor parallel to it we can decrease the resistance of the circuit so, we can discharge the battery faster, but we cannot get higher power output (energy is wasted in the resistor). Is there a way to get higher power output by discharging the battery faster without wasting energy.

Comment: That's the 5th paragraph of my answer : if you have a fixed load (constant resistance), then the only solution is to use a converter to convert the battery voltage to a higher voltage. If for exemple you multiply by 2 the voltage, then the current is also multiplied by 2, therefore the power is multiplied by 4

Comment: Now i understand, Thank you. Can we use this method to discharge a battery to charge another battery faster (faster discharging and faster charging)

Comment: you could, as long as you remain within the (recharge) current limits of your second battery, and you manage to avoid overcharging. It's not "easy" however to add all the protection you then need, and dangerous if you do it wrong (battery might ignite or explose if overcharged). This starts to be quite out of topic for this question, so if you wish to discuss this, please open a new question (and provide more information about your setup (battery types, voltages, currents, if you have datasheets, ...)